# Source for parts to make a BlinkM I2C bus cable? (from todbot blog)

Tags: blinkm, i2c

I came across this post on the todbot blog about controlling BlinkMs over an I2C bus:
http://todbot.com/blog/2008/06/17/get-on-the-blinkm-bus-with-a-blinkm-cylon/

I LOVE his connectors, but cannot find a good source for the ribbon cable/push through connectors...

Has anyone seen where I can get these easily? Its such an elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the sources I list at the bottom of my post not working for you?  Or are you looking for something local to Australia or Europe?

The ribbon cable is bog standard ribbon cable for IDC connectors.  I use a roll of 40-wire wide cable that I peel off the number of wires I need (eight in the case of the 2x4 IDC connectors I use in that post)

As for the 2x4 IDC connectors, they are a very standard form-factor as well, special only in that they are 2x4 instead of the more common 2x5 or 2x8 sizes.  You can use those longer sizes if you want (or even the 2x20 kind used by IDE hard drives), but then you have to be more careful about alignment. :)

Updated:

The Jaycar link that penjuin has for a 2x5 connector will work.  [Au.farnell.com](http://au.farnell.com) has an entry for the exact part I use: [FCI 71600-308LF](http://au.farnell.com/fci/71600-308lf/pcb-connector/dp/1630555?Ntt=FCI71600-308LF), but currently show none in stock local to you.

Marcus, if Little Bird Electronics wanted to get into stocking various kinda weird connectors like these, you should check out [4ucon](http://www.4uconnector.com). They have the [2x8 IDC connector](http://www.4uconnector.com/online/itemagrid.asp?seriesdesp=2.54++IDC+SOCKET&seriesno=0413&GroupNo=04&groupdesp=IDC+Plug+%2F+Socket+%2F+Latch+Header+%2F+Box+Header&itemnum=906&sample=0&seriesnum=46&) as well as many many others.  There lead time is at least a month usually and minimum order quantity is several hundred, but their prices are very good.

Comment: To be honest, I did not see the links right away, so went hunting for a local distributor. The 2x4 IDC connectors I could not find anywhere, and could only find ugly rainbow ribbon cable to pull apart.

I have now found your links and will order from OS!

Thanks so much!

Comment: PS By 'Local' i meant Australia ;-)

Comment: Tod I'm also interested! 

Cheers, 

Marcus

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned you are in Australia; try searching Jaycar for "IDC Line Socket" and "IDC Cable". The smallest connector they sell is [2x5](http://jaycar.com.au/productView.asp?ID=PS0984&keywords=idc&form=KEYWORD) and the smallest ribbon cable is [16 wires](http://jaycar.com.au/productView.asp?ID=WM4502&keywords=IDC+ribbon&form=KEYWORD) but you can easily tear that cable apart. You just get some connectors, run the ribbon through and put them in a vice; simple!